# show the route for longer distances between two points using polyline points

Tags: java, android, java-me, google-maps-api-2

I have created an app where I have to show multiple route from my current location to the user's input location in a listview and then on the click of the list item the respective has to show,well I have done this but I had done this overview_polyline because of which I am not getting the right paths,so I have now taking all the points from "polyline"(which is inside the steps in json url).I have done this but the only problem I am facing is I am not able to show the route where distance is big enough from my current location.
I need an example or idea for this, Please I am too much confuse with this,
Thank you in advance